# Google Cloud Build Reject build failed with error: Build {build-id} might not have been rejected: Precondition check failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I would like to reject old builds from the Google Cloud Build console. When I use the console following the instructions from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/approve-builds#rejecting_builds), I receive an error:

```
Build {build-id} might not have been rejected: Precondition check failed.
```

I have tried to cancel the build. It gives me a generic error response:

```
The attempted action failed, please try again.

Tracking number: {tracking number}
```

I have tried using the gcloud command:

```
NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found
```

However, the build is still in the Cloud Build console.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your case, I was able to reject/cancel builds which were pending approval.

Steps I followed,

- First you have to create trigger builds, by providing all the
  information as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger) .
- I selected, `Event as push to branch`, `source as USERNAME/cloud-build-samples(GitHub App)`, `branch : ^main$`,
  `configuration : Cloud Build configuration file (yaml or json)`,
  `location: Repository`, `Cloudbuild configuration file location: quickstart-automate/cloudbuild.yaml`
- Check the box of Approval to configure build triggers which require
  approval before the build executes.
- After your build trigger is ready, commit a change to your cloned
  cloud-build-samples repository on your own GitHub account by updating
  your source code and then Commit your changes to GitHub by running
  the following commands:

  `git add quickstart-automate/main.go`

  `git commit -m "update text"`

  `git push`

You may be prompted to enter your credentials when pushing code to your repository. If prompted, enter your username and [authentication token that you generated from your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). You have now pushed a change to your repository. Your push will result in an automatic build by your trigger.

- Now provide the gcloud commands to reject this pending approval
  trigger build.

  `gcloud alpha builds reject BUILD_ID  --project=PROJECT_ID \`

Note : BUILD_ID is present in the Execution details of that particular build. Click on the specific trigger with build number, check the build details, you will find Build id. Use this build id in the gcloud command for rejecting pending builds.

[image]

- After running the command, the build was rejected and the console UI
  showed the same.
- Also I tried rejecting the pending builds using the console/UI that
  worked too.
- Check  this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/troubleshooting#4xx_client_errors) when you see 4xx errors.